# Add Custom Variable in every Analytics Tag of a container

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Using GTM, is it possibile to add a custom variable in every Google Analytics Classic Tag at once?
I have a container with 50 GA tags and now i have to pass a custom variable to each of them, and it seems possibile only doing it updating every single tag.
I've tried to pass a custom variable in a tag fired on all pages at page view, setting it at session level but debugging with WASP i find that only on pageview the custom variable is passed to the _utm.gif and not on other events.

Anyone has any clue for this?
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to do this programmatically using the [GTM API](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/reference/#Variables).